# Field Errors after using keystone-storage-adapter-s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, keystonejs

I am looking for help debugging the message "Field Errors" I receive as a browser popup when trying to upload an image through the Keystone CMS.
[image]

I am using the [npm package keystone-storage-adapter-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystone-storage-adapter-s3). For some context, I am trying to upload images to an AWS S3 bucket and later retrieve them as part of a website's content using the Keystone CMS. I am pretty new to AWS S3, but trying.

Here is the image model in question.

```
const keystone = require('keystone');
const Types = keystone.Field.Types;

const Image = new keystone.List('Image');

const storage = new keystone.Storage({
    adapter: require('keystone-storage-adapter-s3'),
    s3: {
        key: process.env.S3_KEY, // required; defaults to process.env.S3_KEY
        secret: process.env.S3_SECRET, // required; defaults to process.env.S3_SECRET
        bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET, // required; defaults to process.env.S3_BUCKET
        region: process.env.S3_REGION, // optional; defaults to process.env.S3_REGION, or if that's not specified, us-east-1
        uploadParams: { // optional; add S3 upload params; see below for details
          ACL: 'public-read',
        },
    },
    schema: {
        bucket: true, // optional; store the bucket the file was uploaded to in your db
        etag: true, // optional; store the etag for the resource
        path: true, // optional; store the path of the file in your db
        url: true, // optional; generate & store a public URL
    },
});

Image.add({
    name: { type: String },
    file: { type: Types.File, storage: storage },
});

Image.register();
```

I believe I've filled out the region, bucket name, secret (random secure string), and even created a new key that's stored securely as well in a .env file.

Here is the error I receive in the browser console.

```
packages.js:33 POST http://localhost:3000/keystone/api/images/5bf2c27e05ba79178cd7d2be 500 (Internal Server Error)
a @ packages.js:33
i @ packages.js:33
List.updateItem @ admin.js:22863
updateItem @ admin.js:15021
r @ packages.js:16
a @ packages.js:14
s @ packages.js:14
d @ packages.js:14
v @ packages.js:14
r @ packages.js:17
processEventQueue @ packages.js:14
r @ packages.js:16
handleTopLevel @ packages.js:16
i @ packages.js:16
perform @ packages.js:17
batchedUpdates @ packages.js:16
i @ packages.js:16
dispatchEvent @ packages.js:16
```

These are the permission settings of my S3 bucket.

- Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects: False
- Remove public access granted through public ACLs: False
- Block new public bucket policies: True
- Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies: True

These are similar questions, but I believe have to do with Keystone's previous implementation of Knox.

- ["Field errors"](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-storage-adapter-s3/issues/9)
- [Field errors in s3 file upload](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/3345)

I found the [debug package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) in use within `node_modules/keystone/fields/types/file/FileType.js` and enabled it. I received the following debug messages when attempting to upload an image.

```
$ DEBUG=keystone:fields:file node keystone.js

------------------------------------------------
KeystoneJS v4.0.0 started:
keystone-s3 is ready on http://0.0.0.0:3000
------------------------------------------------

GET /keystone/images/5bf2c27e05ba79178cd7d2be 200 17.446 ms
GET /keystone/api/images/5bf2c27e05ba79178cd7d2be?drilldown=true 304 3.528 ms
  keystone:fields:file [Image.file] Validating input:  upload:File-file-1001 +0ms
  keystone:fields:file [Image.file] Validation result:  true +1ms
  keystone:fields:file [Image.file] Uploading file for item 5bf2c27e05ba79178cd7d2be: { fieldname: 'File-file-1001',
  originalname: 'oof.PNG',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'C:\\Users\\Dylan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
  filename: '42c161c1c36a84a244a2cf09d327afd4',
  path:
   'C:\\Users\\Dylan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\42c161c1c36a84a244a2cf09d327afd4',
  size: 6684 } +0ms
POST /keystone/api/images/5bf2c27e05ba79178cd7d2be 500 225.027 ms
```

This message looks promising, so I will keep looking through this to see if I can debug any more information.

Edit: Progress! I searched the Keystone package for "Field errors" and found where the error message is set. Debugging that location revealed another error.

**"InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."**

The search continues.

Answer (score 1):

I was mixing up my "key" and "secret".

As per the [keystone-storage-adapter-s3 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystone-storage-adapter-s3), required are your "key" and "secret". Having inexperience with AWS, and some with web development, I thought the secret was a random secure string (like you would sign a cookie with) and the key was my secret key.

**wrong**

- "key" : Secret Key
- "secret" : Random secure key.

**correct**

- "key": Key ID
- "secret": Secret key.

Turns out I was wrong. The "key" is my key id, and the "secret" is my secret key. Settings those correctly in my .env file allowed me to upload a file to the S3 bucket.